# SQL Totals for year and also set period

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I have the following SQL database: tablename

```
date        fname   surname     points  display
2015-08-08  John    Lennon      5       1
2015-08-16  Ringo   Starr       2       1
2015-08-24  Paul    McCartney   3       1
2015-10-07  George  Harrison    1       1
2015-10-15  John    Lennon      3       1
2015-10-23  Ringo   Starr       5       1
2015-12-07  George  Harrison    1       1
2015-12-14  Ringo   Starr       5       1
2015-12-22  George  Harrison    3       1
2016-02-03  Paul    McCartney   4       1
2016-02-13  John    Lennon      5       1
2016-02-20  Paul    McCartney   1       1
2016-04-04  Ringo   Starr       2       1
2016-04-09  George  Harrison    2       1
2016-04-20  John    Lennon      5       1
```

At present I just use this database to pull the total points for the current year where display = '1' and use the following code:

```
SELECT id, fname, surname, points, CONCAT(surname,forename) 'fullname', SUM(points) AS total_points
FROM tablename 
WHERE date >= '2016-01-01' AND display ='1' 
GROUP BY fname, surname
ORDER BY total_points DESC, surname ASC, forename ASC
```

However I would like to add an extra piece of data to the result, giving me the points over the past 15 days.  I can pull this on its own by using:

```
SELECT id, fname, surname, points, CONCAT(surname,forename) 'fullname', SUM(points) AS fifteenday_points
FROM tablename 
WHERE date >= '2016-04-08' AND display ='1' 
GROUP BY fname, surname
ORDER BY total_points DESC, surname ASC, forename ASC
```

So, how do I go about this?  Do I need to use some sort of join?  If so, where do I even begin due to the differing WHERE statements?  Or is there a simple addition I can make to the first query which will allow me to return the fifteenday_points data?

Answer (score 1):

You can join them in this way:

```
SELECT fname, surname, CONCAT(surname,fname) AS fullname,  SUM(points) AS total_points, fifteenday_points
FROM tablename JOIN (
    SELECT CONCAT(surname,forename) 'fullname', SUM(points) AS fifteenday_points
    FROM tablename 
    WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY  AND display ='1' 
    GROUP BY fullname) AS fifteen_days
    ON tablename.fullname = fifteen_days.fullname
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND display ='1' 
GROUP BY fullname
ORDER BY total_points DESC, fullname ASC
```

I also changed the conditions on datas

Comment: Great! But why dont you simply sort by fullname?
`ORDER BY total_points DESC, fullname ASC`

Comment: Tried this but I get the following: #1054 - Unknown column 'tablename.fullname' in 'on clause'

Comment: Try to edit the `SELECT` with `CONCAT(surname,fname) AS fullname`

Comment: Thanks guys, but still returning: #1054 - Unknown column 'tablename.fullname' in 'on clause'

Comment: Got it working after making a few changes. I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tablename.fname, tablename.surname, CONCAT(tablename.surname,tablename.fname) AS 'fullname',  SUM(points) AS total_points, fifteenday_points
FROM tablename JOIN (
SELECT tablename.fname, tablename.surname, SUM(points) AS fifteenday_points
FROM tablename 
WHERE enddate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY  AND display ='1' 
GROUP BY tablename.surname, tablename.fname) AS fifteen_days
ON tablename.surname = fifteen_days.surname AND tablename.fname = fifteen_days.fname
WHERE YEAR(enddate) = YEAR(NOW()) AND display ='1' 
GROUP BY tablename.surname, tablename.fname
ORDER BY total_points DESC, tablename.surname ASC, tablename.fname ASC;
```

Thanks to Vitto and Reto for putting me on the right path.